# .htaccess and php rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I can not do simple and does not understand what's the problem.
I just want to create a nice looking URL.

My link looks like this:
`www.mysite.com/coach/23/victor`

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

in `functions.php` file I'm trying to get information like this:

```
$page_type=$_GET['p'];
$page_type=$_GET['id'];
$page_type=$_GET['title'];
```

In `index.php` I include `functions.php` and make a switch.

```
switch($page_type){
  case "home": include "home.php";
               break;
}
```

Comment: Is the answer going to be something to do with greedy regex? Who knows.

Comment: Overwriting `$page_type` 3 times in 3 consecutive lines is probably not going to help.

Comment: the error:     Not Found

The requested URL /coach/135 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: i'm sorry, i use like this: $page_type=$_GET['p'];
$id=$_GET['id'];
$title=$_GET['title'];And still not working

Comment: Another issue, the rewrite rules are never going to fire as the example link doesn't contain .html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You didn't ask** any **question**

However just by analysing this what you said. You want to go to

```
www.mysite.com/coach/23/victor
```

wowever all you rewrite rules expect `.html` so the correct url would be

```
www.mysite.com/coach/23/victor.html
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to the site and probably not explained properly
To all work I can write a link in this way:
www.mysite.com/index.php?p=coach&id=20&title=victor
But it does not look good, that's why I want to write more beautiful, but comes like an old link

Comment: Well.. I'm sad to hear that but what EXACTLY went wrong for you? Nobody can read your mind.

Comment: The design was lost, only text without formatting. If I add a link to this CSS file full return to work. Is it possible otherwise?